# react native compare previous state and with current state array with websocket

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i have implemented websocket in my app with the response is take each second from server

```
WS.onMessage((datas) => {

     var letters =  JSON.parse(datas);
  // or something else or use redux


this.setState({    Newdata:letters})

})
```

and response is

```
[{id:1,value:32},{id:2,value:321}]
```

and one second later is the response is

```
[{id:1,value:312},{id:2,value:31}]
```

**note: there is only response each from once source and i want to check the difference between the last newdata array and the current newdata array**
and each second a new message is coming
these data are placed into flatlist
my question is what is the most effective way to do something like this in renderitem
compare previous value and current value

renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
return(current id {id} previous value {previousvalue}  current value {item.value})
}

```
    <FlatList
                   data={this.state.newdata}
                   showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                   style={{width: "100%",height: "100%"}}
    
                   renderItem={this.renderItem}
                   keyExtractor={item => item}
    
    
                   />
```

Comment: Pass both objects as arguments to `renderItem` and then display the appropriate values?

Comment: there is no previous value,the response is changing each second

Comment: If it's changing every second, then there is a previous value.

Comment: it is coming from server based on onmessage function not in app and then stored in newdata in state ,what i am a litte consufed about is how to save the last state and combare with newstate

Comment: Just create a new property inside your `state` - `state = { prevData: [...], currData: [...] }`, then make sure to update these appropriately when data changes, and use them to compare previous objects to current objects.